# How to get first n distinct column value from left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to get is "get first 5 distinct customer's order id values". When I limit below query to 5 it only returns first 4 customer's order id values as expected.(Around the Horn has two different order id) Is there a way to get first 5 distinct customer's order id values?

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;


CustomerName                        OrderID
Alfreds Futterkiste                 10001
Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10308
Antonio Moreno Taquería             10365
Around the Horn                     10355
Around the Horn                     10383
B's Beverages                       10289
Antonio baa                         10444
....                                ....
```

**EDIT:** What I want to get is first 5 distinct customer;

```
Alfreds Futterkiste                 10001 (first customer)
Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  10308 (second customer)
Antonio Moreno Taquería             10365 (third customer)
Around the Horn                     10355 (forth customer)
Around the Horn                     10383 (forth customer)
B's Beverages                       10289 (fifth customer)
```

Here [are](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left) the tables I am working on.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Is there anything unclear?

Comment: Evidently. Otherwise you'd have accepted an answer already

Comment: @Strawberry I have added all tables and other information with link. Even you can test your query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
            SELECT DISTINCT Orders.OrderID, CC.CustomerName

            FROM Customers CC
            LEFT JOIN Orders
            ON CC.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
            inner join  

            (
            SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerName
            FROM Customers
            LEFT JOIN Orders
            ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
            ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName
            LIMIT 5
            ) C 
            ON C.CustomerName=CC.CustomerName

            ORDER BY CC.CustomerName
```

Comment: I am getting error: Couldn't prepare statement (1 near ";" :syntax error)

Comment: @hellzone Note that an OUTER JOIN using a table from which you neither select columns nor order against is completely meaningless

Answer (score -1):

Limit query in 5 with "SELECT TOP 5" and add extra WHERE clause, "WHERE Customers.OrderdId IS NOT NULL"

Comment: It is not about null. I updated my question for you :)